# MDN sitemap/index page?

Tags: javascript, documentation

This is not directly a coding question, but does anyone know if [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) provides an index or sitemap page? (Before redesign it used to be (https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Sitemap). Basically, I'm looking for all javascript functions/objects listed on one page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/sitemap.xml is working.
https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Sitemap is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/sitemap.xml is working. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Sitemap is not working...

Comment: Great that I was able to help you. :) Thanks for the correction again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference
MDN JavaScript reference.

Comment: No, I'm looking for a page that lists all javascript built-in methods.

Comment: Well they are all there :). The global function properties and methods that belong to any global objects are grouped by that object.